# set cursor position in IE and cursor loses

Tags: internet-explorer, cursor, range

In contenteditable div , I type some words like @ab ,and get a user popup, then if I select user 'abc' in popup by mouse, the user can insert @abc into div  but cursor will lose. If I select user by keycoard, it's ok.

IE:
  //currentRange include @ab 
  //elem is contenteditable div

```
    elem = $this.get(0);
    elem.focus();

    var inputStr = <a href="userlink">@abc</a>

    currentRange.pasteHTML(inputStr);   

    // set cursor position  
    var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
    if(bookmark) {
        r.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
        r.select();
        bookmark = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `pasteHTML()` on the range after selecting it and the cursor will automatically move to the position immediately after the pasted content:

```
elem = $this.get(0);
elem.focus();

var inputStr = '<a href="userlink">@abc</a>';

// set cursor position  
var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
if(bookmark) {
    r.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
    r.select();
    bookmark = null;
}
r.pasteHTML(inputStr);
```